# Grails - specifying a plugin as zip?

Tags: plugins, grails, groovy, jenkins

In grails, you can install a zip version of a plugin with `grails install-plugin myplugin.zip`. This adds the file to your project and modifies application.properties. I tried putting the zip in `/lib`, but other developers are unable to build without first manually running `grails install-plugin myplugin.zip`.

Is there a way to get the zip file to resolve automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails can load a plugin from anywhere. For example, if you add the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.location.jsecurity = "/home/dilbert/dev/plugins/grails-jsecurity"
```

It will load the `jsecurity` plugin from the location specified

Answer (score 0):

In-place plugins work a treat for all plugins and updates your application realtime as you are testing. Peter Ledbrook has written a very good blog on this ( http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/01/whats-a-plugin-oriented-architecture/ ), see the paragraph on 'in-place plugins'.